# How to display (NS)Errors in UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift

I have found myself repeatedly writing the following lines of code

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Something went wrong", message: "This is why something went wrong", preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

And then I would populate the `title`s and `message` of the alert and buttons from `NSError` objects. In search of a better, more efficient way I came across [Apple's Error Handling Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorObjectsDomains/ErrorObjectsDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH202-SW3), which seemed promising:

> **Note:** Beginning with OS X version 10.4, you can use the `alertWithError:`class method of `NSAlert` as a convenience for creating `NSAlert` objects to use when displaying alert dialogs or sheets. The method extracts the localized information from the passed-in `NSError` object for its message text, informative text, and button titles. You may also use the `presentError:` message to display error alerts.

The `NSError` class contains properties specifically meant to be displayed in an alert view (at least for OS X). Unfortunately, I was not able to find a similar approach for iOS.

**Is there an easy, convenient way to display Error objects in an Alert in iOS?**

Answer (score 1):

Write your own extension to `UIAlertController`:

```
extension UIAlertController {
    func alert(with error: Error) -> UIAlertController {
        // Create and setup the alert as needed using the error
        var res = UIAlertController(title: "Something went wrong", message: "Some message", preferredStyle: .alert)

        res.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

        return res
    }
}
```

Update the parameter to use `NSError` if desired and/or add additional parameters as needed to suit your needs.

Then you can use it as follows:

```
let alert = UIAlertController.alert(with: someError)
self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

Comment: This would be the best sort of "last resort" approach. I just think I'm missing something. If there is a convenience method for OS X why wouldn't there be the same for iOS?

Comment: `NSAlert` has the special `init` method specifically for working with an error. `UIAlertController` does not. If you want one, you need to write your own. There are many, many things in macOS that you won't find in iOS. There's nothing "last resort" about this approach.

Comment: "why wouldn't there be the same for iOS" Because there isn't one. Accept reality and move on. You'll be happier. Questions of the form "Why isn't iOS like so-and-so" are not productive or appropriate for Stack Overflow. This site is about how to do things, not moans about why the universe is the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy, convenient way to display Error objects in an Alert in iOS?

`UIAlertController` does **not** have a convenient *(auto-parsing)* way to display an `Error`/`NSError` atm. `UIKit` does not provide any, so you will end up with a custom solution.

Answer (score -1):

`NSError` has `localizedDescription` property which can be shown in `UIAlertController's` message as follow,

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Something went wrong", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

Comment: This is what I meant by I populate those parameters from an `NSError` object. This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.